# Upper bounds for probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Let $X\sim \text{Poi}(\lambda )$, $\lambda>0$. Let $a>2\lambda$.

Show that $P[X\leq a]\leq \text{exp}\left (a-\lambda-a\ln \left (\frac{a}{\lambda}\right )\right )$ using the Markov-inequality with $\phi (x)=e^{\theta x}$ and minimizing over $\theta>0$.

$$$$

I have done the following :

For $\epsilon=\alpha>0$ and $\phi (x)=e^{\theta x}$ we have from the  Markov-innequality: \begin{equation*}P[X\geq \alpha]\leq \frac{E[\phi (|X|)]}{\phi (\alpha)} =\frac{E[e^{\theta X}]}{e^{\theta \alpha}}\end{equation*}
The expected value of $e^{\theta X}$ is \begin{align*}E[e^{\theta X}]&=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)} e^{\theta x}\cdot P[X=x] =\sum_{x=0}^{+\infty} e^{\theta x}\cdot \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}\cdot e^{-\lambda} =e^{-\lambda}\cdot \sum_{x=0}^{+\infty} e^{\theta x}\cdot \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}  \end{align*}
How can we continue?

Comment: In c) what is $n$ in $\ln n(a/\lambda)$? And presumably we can set $\theta = 1$ since there is no $\theta$ in the solution?

Comment: The $n$ is a typo. I corrected it. We have to minimize over $\theta>0$. Is my attempt so far correct? So from that step we have to minimize? Or what is the next step? @Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{+\infty}e^{\theta x}\cdot\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}=\sum_{x=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(\lambda e^\theta)^x}{x!}=\exp\{\lambda e^\theta\}
$$
So we have
$$
P[X\geq a]\leq \exp\{(e^\theta-1)\lambda-\theta a\}
$$
Then minimizing over $\theta>0$

Comment: Do we have that the inequality $P[X\geq a]\leq \exp\{(e^\theta-1)\lambda-\theta a\}$ holds for all $\theta$ and so also for $\theta_{min}$ and so we have $P[X\geq a]\leq \exp\{(e^\theta_{min}-1)\lambda-\theta_{min} a\}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, all $\theta>0$.

Comment: And so also for the $\theta$ for which the right side gets mininmum. Great! Thank you very much for the clarifications!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar My pleasure :)